# Excel - VBA: Preciso de apoio para lincar a função Max

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Como posso referenciar uma coluna de uma certa *sheet* através do comando abaixo no VBA?

```
Application.WorksheetFunction.Max
```

Answer (score 1):

Basta referenciar o **Range** que você precisa.

Exemplo:

```
Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Worksheets("Plan1").Range("A1:A10"))
```

Comment: Grato pelo retorno.

Comment: Estou criando um cadastro de clientes. Em uma Textbox que criei em meu userform, eu quero que seus valores tenham uma ordem de crescimento começando de 1, depois 2 e assim por diante. Assimsendo, criei o código a seguir: TextBox2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(sheet2.Columns(1)) + 1. Quando tento executar o código ele falha nesta linha

Comment: Oi @LázaroGouveia, creio que o ideal seria criar uma outra questão para isso, pois o intuito do stackoverflow é que dúvidas que possam ser comum entre outras pessoas, sejam respondidas aqui e fiquem como uma grande fonte de soluções.

Comment: grato pelo suporte? Sou novo no VBA e gostaria imenso de dominar a linguagem. Existe alguma forma de mantermos contacto de outra forma, além daqui?